# Laravel 4 fluent query is returning duplicated records when in MySQL there is none

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a small problem with my query.

I have a view that displays the latest movies limit 10.

The problem I'm having is that it is showing records twice.

When I check the database there is only one record so there is not duplicated records. My view generates:

```
Clerks II
Clerks II
50/50
50/50
```

When it suppose to be only 1 of each not 2 of each.

This is my view:

```
@foreach ($latest as $last)
<li>{{HTML::link('movies/' .$last->idMovie, $last->c00) }}</li>
@endforeach
```

This is the query

on Model:

```
public static function latest()
{
 $latest = DB::table('movieview')
  ->select('movieview.*','art.*')
  ->join('art', 'art.media_id', '=', 'movieview.idMovie')
  ->where('art.type', '=', 'fanart')
  ->orderBy('dateAdded', 'DESC')
  ->take(10)
  ->get();

  return $latest;
}
```

And lastly my controller.

I'm using a `view::Composer` because is a sidebar sort of like a widget:

```
View::composer('site/latest', function($view){
         $latest = Movies::latest();  
         $newmovie = Movies::newMovie();

            $view->with(array(
            'latest'=> $latest,
            'newmovie'=> $newmovie
            ));
        });
```

On a side note I moved my laravel installation into a new server. On the old server it works just fine. Am I missing something? I did all the things like composer update composer dump-autoload. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: What does the actual data result of your query look like? Do you have multiple art items per movie? If so, your join will create multiple rows with the movie part being duplicated, and the art being unique. You could likely bypass that using Eloquent relationships and eager loading.

Comment: nvm solved needed to add ->where('.art.media_type', '=', 'movie') on the query because for some reason xbmc was adding meedia_type set and was getting 2 results. now is working fine wierd damn xbmc.

Answer (score 1):

One Way to debug this kind of problems is to enable the General Query Log on your development computer, that way you can actually see the query that is being generated and discard a logic issue.

You can activate the general query log in the following way

Run this two queries in your mysql server

`SET global general_log = 1;`

`SET global log_output = 'table';`

Then you can read the log by using this query:

`select * from mysql.general_log`